# How to use celery and dependency_injector together?

Tags: dependency-injection, celery

I'm using FastAPI, and the dependencies of FastAPI are managed by the dependency_injector library.

With the addition of Celery functionality, there arose a need to use the dependencies used in FastAPI in Celery's workers as well.

What should I do?

So I proceeded as follows, but it doesn't work.

```py
# celery.py
from celery import Celery

from app.core.config import get_app_settings

settings = get_app_settings()
worker = Celery(
    "worker",
    backend=settings.celery_backend_url,
    broker=settings.celery_broker_url,
    include=["app.worker.tasks"],
)

worker.conf.update(
    result_expires=3600,
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from app.core.containers import Container

    settings = get_app_settings()
    container = Container()
    container.config.from_pydantic(settings)

    worker.start()
```

```py
# tasks.py
import asyncio

from celery import Task

import app.db.postgres.repositories as pg_repositories

from .celery import container, worker


class Task1(Task):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.container = container
        self.task_repository: pg_repositories.TaskRepository = self.container.task_repository()

    async def task1(self):
        ...

@worker.task(ignore_result=False, bind=True, base=Task1, name="tasks")
def task1(self):
    asyncio.run(self.task1())
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'container' from 'app.worker.celery' (/Users/.../app/worker/celery.py)

However, it works well when I directly inject in the Task class.
But in my opinion, as multiple workers will be started, I think it's inefficient to inject for each worker when multiple workers are started.